# Stacking Text Component With Bootstrap Without Duplicating HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get text to be full width on a large device and then stacked on a mobile device with larger text.

I realize I can do something like displaying none for the large text if the browser is small and then setting three text blocks to col-12 for the small device, but that seems like a lot of html duplication. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

My code is below. I recognize I can override the font size with the bootstrap overrides for a small device. I just need help stacking the font.

I included a codepend here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRQZdR

```
<h1 class="title-text-md col-lg-12"><strong>Example Text to Be stacked with larger font on mobile</strong></h1>


 @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
      .title-text-md {
         font-size: 20px;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css this might do the trick.

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
h1{font-size: 30px;}
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
h1{font-size: 4px;}
}
   @media (max-width: @screen-md) {
h1{font-size: 400px;}
}
 @media (max-width: @screen-md) {
h1{font-size: 40px;}
  }
 h1{
font-size: 1.4em;
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just asked this question, if you may know the answer @neophyte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178461/bootstrap-media-queries-rails-error

Comment: I am sorry. but I have no idea about rails. Still I will try to find a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks @neophyte. I think it has more to do with the variables than rails processors, which may be better